# AJAX Toolkit AutoCompleteExtender with a *PAGE* service?

Tags: asp.net, autocomplete

I have an application currently using the AJAX Toolkit AutoCompleteExtender to extend a textbox. It is using a webservice to select and retrieve the data. The docs for the toolkit say that you can also use a page service and I have been trying for days to get that to wrok - both in the vs2005 and the 2.0 framework version and vs2008 and the 3.5 framework version (the attrubutes for the page service are slightly different in each version). I cannot get either version to work with a page service - both work just fine with a web service.

Has anyone had any luck with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Have You checked the following:

- Your page method is (You really mean page method, not page service?) is static.
- The method return a List or string[].
- The parameters are (string prefixText, int count). Order and case matters.

You can also look at http://allwrong.wordpress.com/2007/03/13/ms-ajax-autocomplete-extender-using-a-page-method/ .

/Andreas

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at your page with either [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in FireFox or [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) with IE to actually see what (if anything) is going on with the scripts and network calls? Firebug's script tab will show you nicely what script methods have been loaded, and will show you network traffic between the browser and server on the Net tab, while Fiddler will mostly allow you to analyse and edit network traffic.

Are you using master pages, and is the control on the master page or the page itself - you can't have page methods on a masterpage?

Comment: Using MasterPages - everything is on the content page except the ScriptManager which I place on the MasterPage so that all content pages have it. Page method is in code behind of content page.

Comment: Hmm, that all sounds about right - have you tried fiddler or firebug then? That would be my next step - see what is actually happening with the JS and over the network.

Comment: Good luck, let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

Have +1'd Zalph as his answer tipped me off. The method must be in a page. I had mine in a user control!